# Apparent mixed-mode arithmetic from a Fortran intrinsic function

Tags: fortran

What I'm doing is very straightforward. Here are the relevant declarations:

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_Fortran_env, dp=>REAL64 !modern DOUBLE PRECISION
REAL(dp), PARAMETER :: G_H2_alpha = 1.57D+04, G_H2_beta = 5.3D+03, G_H2_gamma = 4.5D+03
REAL(dp) :: E_total_alpha, E_total_beta, E_total_gamma, P_H2_sed
```

Usage:

```
P_H2_sed = G_H2_alpha * E_total_alpha + G_H2_beta * E_total_beta * G_H2_gamma * E_total_gamma
```

where `E_total_alpha`, `E_total_beta`, and `E_total_gamma` are just running `dp` totals inside various loops. I ask for the nearest integer `NINT(P_H2_sed)` and get -2147483648, which looks like mixed-mode arithmetic. The float `P_H2_sed` returns 2529548272025.4888, so I would expect `NINT` to return 2529548272026. I didn't think it was possible to get this kind of result from an intrinsic function. I haven't seen this since my days with the old F77 compiler. I'm doing something bad, but *what* is the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NINT`, by default, returns an integer with default type parameter, that usually is equivalent to `int32`.

An integer of this kind cannot represent a number as high as `2529548272026`. The maximum representable number is `2^31-1`, that is `2147483647`. The result you are getting is similar to that, but is the lowest representable number, `-2147483648` (equivalent o all 32 bits set to 1).

To get a result of other kind from `NINT`, pass an optional parameter named `kind`, like this: `NINT(P_H2_sed, kind=int64)`.